# Checking whether sequence $ x_n = \ln(n^2 + 1) - \ln(n) $ converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms

I have to show whether

$$
x_n = \ln(n^2 + 1) - \ln(n)
$$

converges or diverges.

I can write

$$
x_n = \ln(n^2 + 1) - \ln(n) = \ln\left(\frac{n^2+1}{n}\right) = \ln\left(n + \frac{1}{n}\right).
$$

I know that $n+\frac{1}{n} \to \infty$ for $n \to \infty$.

Since $\ln(x) \to \infty$ for $x \to \infty$, the series $x_n = \ln(n^2 + 1)-\ln(n)$ diverges.

Is this correct? I think it is too easy. Have I forgot something? Can I use some lemma?

Comment: It's correct :)

Comment: Alternate approach Hint: how does $\ln (n^2+1)$ compare to $\ln (n^2)$?

Comment: Series or sequence?

Comment: Are you considering a series, or a sequence?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's a sequence

Comment: I don't know how $\ln(n^2 +1)$ compares to $\ln(n^2)$. I know that $n^2$ is always positive and that $\ln(x)$ is increasing for increasing $x$, so $\ln(n^2+1)$ must be greater than $\ln(n^2)$.

Comment: but how can I use it to determine convergence?

Comment: @Jamgreen, your proof is absolutely correct, you have nothing to worry about